# Yarn nodemanager not starting up. Getting no errors

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, daemon

I have Hadoop 2.7.4 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to run it in Pseudo Mode.
I have a '/hadoop' partition mounted for all my hadoop files, NameNode and DataNode files.

My core-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

My hdfs-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/hadoop/nodes/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/hadoop/nodes/datanode</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

My mapred-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>Map-Reduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

My yarn-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>Map-Reduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

After running

```
$ start-dfs.sh 
$ start-yarn.sh
$ jps
```

I get the following daemons running.

```
2800 ResourceManager
2290 NameNode
4242 Jps
2440 DataNode
2634 SecondaryNameNode
```

start-yarn.sh gives me:

```
$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4/logs/yarn-abdy-resourcemanager-abdy-hadoop.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4/logs/yarn-abdy-nodemanager-abdy-hadoop.out
```

The nodemanager daemon does not seem to start at all.
I've tried for 2 days to fix this issue but I cannot seem to find a fix. Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

#### If your going to start hadoop daemons for the first time.

First you have to format your namenode :

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

> Before formatting namenode make sure you delete existing  
> /hadoop/nodes/namenode and /hadoop/nodes/datanode folders

Then you execute:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Once formatting of namenode is done.
you execute following commands.

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

Comment: I has already done all that. The problem was NodeManager was running out of RAM, I had to limit the RAM usage allowed to NodeManager for it to work.

Comment: Can you plz tell me how you did this @aBDYsINGH?